# DataServiceContext entityTracker member becomes null when calling AddLink()!

Tags: c#, clr, wcf-data-services, odata, wcf-rest

I have a very strange problem upon calling `AddLink` method of the `DataServiceContext` instance. The call is made inside a POST method of a WCF REST service which consumes the data service. I will not get into details related to this service architecture but if you have any objections please state them.

So, this is the method implementation:

```
    public DEvent PostEvent(DEvent inputEvent)
    {
        if (inputEvent == null)
            return null;
        try
        {                
            var ctx = EFTestDbEntities.CreateContext();
            var ev = new DEvent();

            // populate with data... not worth mentioning.

            ctx.AddToDEvents(ev); // No problem here...
            var es = new LDEvent_CEventState();
            ctx.AddToLDEvent_CEventState(es); // No problem here, aswell...
            // Next line throws NullReferenceException!!!
            ctx.AddLink(ev, "LDEvent_CEventStates", es); 
            ev.LDEvent_CEventStates.Add(es);                           
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            return inputEvent;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(exc.ToString());
            throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

Calling `AddLink` throws a `NullReferenceException` which is not documented on MSDN for this particular function, [please check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.addlink%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).The function is supposed to throw argument null and invalid operation exceptions. Please notice that there two more calls which involve the entity tracker before throwing null exception.

Debugging the code with the help of the Reflector I've noticed that `ctx.entityTracker` member becomes null upon entering `AddLink()`. I followed entity tracker field from instance creation, and found no reason it should change. I might have missed something, but I doubt it. I inserted a more operations before `AddLink()` but the exception is always thrown in the same spot.

When I tested this in a WPF application there were no problems at all and behaves as expected.

What am I missing?

Need to mention that I'm using VS 2012 and got OData V3 using Nuget. Services are hosted in IIS 7.5 and both are on the same application pool and web site. The packages included in the project are:

- Microsoft.Data.Edm, 5.4.0
- Microsoft.Data.OData, 5.4.0
- Microsoft.Data.Services.Client, 5.4.0, this is where `DataServiceContext` resides
- System.Spatial, 5.4.0

So, is this a CLR issue? Or OData API? Or IIS? `ServiceHost` or `DataServiceHost`?

Any help in trying to make me understand what happens here is very appreciated and I really hope I'm missing something. Meanwhile, I will restart my work station and hope that all these problems go away :)

Comment: I also tried this code in a WPF app and worked, so I guess it's an IIS related issue.